# Drupal 7 images not showing in Articles

Tags: php, image, drupal, content-management-system, cck

My Configuration : Installed MAMP, then copied drupal to htdocs folder. Configured drupal. Added CKEditor, Transliteration, and CKEditor SWF modules. I created an article and uploaded an image from the create Article page. The image uploaded successfully but is not showing up anywhere. It looks like it is trying to fetch the image from the wrong location.

Image URL on page: localhost:8888/drupal/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/field/image/dsc_1233_2.jpg

Actual Image location : localhost:8888/drupal/sites/default/files/field/image/dsc_1233_2.jpg

The above 2 URL's are different. What should I change to make this work? Thank You

Comment: Did you upload the image using the upload module so Drupal could register it? Or did you just transplant it into the directory?

Comment: The difference between the URL is normal, Drupal will not show the image you've uploaded but a copy according to the image style set in your configuration. This way you can change the display style without ever affecting the original upload.

Comment: give permission to files folder

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Increasing memory_limit in php.ini fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

i guess u have to install IMCE module http://drupal.org/project/imce ...
if this doesn't work check this out... http://drupaldome.com/how-setup-ckeditor-imce